# My C program is exiting with a non-zero status and I don't know why. Currently running the code in repl.it

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, random, nested-loops

Hi I'm currently running a code in c programming, and it keeps exiting with a non-zero status.

The code is being used for a sudoku game and what I'm essentially trying to do is generate a random 9x9 2D array. After randomly generating it, I have a function checking if the grid is a valid grid. I don't know why I'm getting a non-zero status.There might be something wrong with the method of how I'm randomly generating the numeber but I'm not sure. Help is appreciated thank you.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int check(int list[][9]){
    // Disable stdout buffering
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    int i, j, x, y, ans = 0, sum = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){               //This nested for loop checks if columns and rows are correct
      sum = 0;
      sum2 = 0;
      for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        sum += list[i][j];
        sum2 += list[j][i];
        if((j == 8) && ((sum != 45) || (sum2 != 45)))
         ans = 1;
      }
    }

    for(x=0;x<3;x++){         //This nested for loop checks if boxes are right
      for(y=0;y<3;y++){
        sum3=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            sum3+= list[i+(3*y)][j+(3*x)];
            if((i==2 && j==2) && (sum3 != 45))
              ans = 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return ans;
}




int main(void){
  // Disable stdout buffering
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  int list[9][9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};


  int i, j, r;

  for(;;i++){

    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
       for(j=0; j<9; j++){
        srand(time(NULL));
        r = rand() % ((9 + 1 - 1) + 1);
        list[i][j] = r;
      }
    }

    if(check(list[i][j]) == 0)
      break;
  }

  printf("done");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me guess.  Do you see the message after you press the close button?

Comment: Also, this is C, not C++. You should remove the C++ tag.

Comment: 1) Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and see if you can simplify your example. 2) What is the purpose of the outermost `for` loop in `main`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: We do not know what it is being compiled as.

Comment: I do believe that Sudoko range is 1..9, where as `rand() % 9` is 0..8.  Maybe you wanted `(rand() % 9) + 1)`?

Comment: What were the results when you used a *debugger*?  Which statement is causing the issue?  What are the expected values of the variable?  What are the actuals?  Please **edit** your post with the answers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why can't _you_ remove the tag? You have suffeicent reputation.

Comment: @leaf Because I want OP to not make the same mistake again. But you're right, I should have commented *and* edited.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Also, sorry if that came across as rude, I forget to mention I meant no ill will in my previous comment.

Comment: @leaf: No, the OP is the only one who knows what language is being used, so the OP is the only one who should make the edit. Further reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281387/560648

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What does that have to do with language choice?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"What does that have to do with language choice?"* What do you mean?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Well you wrote me a reply that seems to have nothing to do with my message. Oh well.

Comment: @Joshua: Actually you don't know whether it's a C or a C++ question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops. I was too sleepy to properly read I guess.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Okay :)

Answer (score 3):

- The function `check()` expects an `int[][9]` array, and you are calling it with a number: the call to `check(list[i][j])` should be `check(list)`.
- In the statement `for (;;i++)` the value of `i` is undefined.
- You may want to move the `srand()` outside the loop -- initialization should be done only once.
- `(9+1-1)+1` is a complicated way of writing `10`...

Comment: Thank you, and I had a question, do you think there's a better way to make a random, valid, sudoku template? Because although my code works, it's extremely rare that it comes up with a valid template.

Comment: @KiranBhatia: [How can I generate Sudoku puzzles](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56149/how-can-i-generate-sudoku-puzzles).